# Цвет текста в С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, color

Есть какие-то варианты как поменять цвет текста в консоли (Visual Studio) что б допустим строчка сверху была жёлтого цвета а снизу красного и не через system("color __") так как system меняет весь текст на то цвет которий указан.

Comment: WriteConsoleOutputAttribute

Comment: а что, на консоли нет подходящих инструментов?